# Fault injection with Knative serving

Tags: istio, knative-serving, knative-functions

I am trying to capture knative serving behavior in the context of n/w delay/latency. I know istio provides a way to introduce 'fault injection' to simulate the n/w latency and test the app resiliency and since Knative uses Istio as n/w layer (per my setup) .

All I am trying is to introduce somesort of n/w latency as described is [ISTIO documentation][1]

I am having a hard time to find a way to edit the corresponding virtual service as Knative takes care of creating the virtual function when a service is deployed.

Is there any ref or example to guide on how to test knative serving by introducing some sort of latency.

My service deployment file is quite simple

`apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: demo-concurrency-kt
namespace: aurora
spec:
template:
metadata:
annotations:
# Target 10 in-flight-requests per pod.
autoscaling.knative.dev/metric: concurrency
autoscaling.knative.dev/target: "10"
autoscaling.knative.dev/targetUtilizationPercentage: "70"
spec:
containerConcurrency: 0
containers:
- image: ghcr.io/knative/autoscale-go:latest

`
[1]: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/

I am running everything in docker desktop K8s environment with Istio as my n/w layer

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated